# Find if char precedes substring

Tags: python, string, substring

I'm trying to find out if a substring ("xyz") is in a string, and if it is, if it has "." in the index to its left. If the substring has the period before it, it is not counted, and if the substring appears without the period it returns true.

I started by checking if the substring is in the string, and appending the index of the substring if it appears. Then I iterated through that list and checked if the index-1 was a ".", and if it was, removed the index. Then if the list still had anything in it, I returned True since the conditions would be met.

I cannot import any module since this is part of a competition, so no regex.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    def xyz_there(a_str):
        #Finds all indexes that xyz starts at
        indexes=[i for i in range(len(a_str)) if a_str.startswith("xyz", i)]

        #Check if sub not in string or string too short
        if len(a_str)<3 or "xyz" not in a_str:
            return False

        #Iterate through indexes, check for preceding "."
        for i in indexes:
            if a_str[i-1] == ".":
                indexes.remove(i)
            if len(indexes)>0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

It works well for the most part, but it has an issue using this test:

```
xyz_there('1.xyz.xyz2.xyz')  #Should return False
```

Given 3 instances of the substring, it finds the period in the first and third instances, but not the second, and I'm not seeing why it would skip that one.

Comment: regex is a built-in functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using [**`count`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count):

```
def xyz_there(s):
    return s.count('xyz') - s.count('.xyz') > 0
```

And example usage:

```
xyz_there('1.xyz.xyz2.xyz')
xyz_there('1.xyz.xyz2xyz')
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Comment: `return s.count('xyz') - s.count('.xyz') > 0` would  also work.

Comment: @MartinEvans it's even better, if you don't mind i can update my answer with your correction

Comment: If anyone knows where I went wrong in my code I'd love to know for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you use `indexes.remove(i)`.  `indexes.remove(i)` removes the first occurrence of `i` in `indexes`.  It does not remove the element at that position.  To do what you want, you will need to use `indexes.pop(i)`.  Also, you are checking the length of `indexes` before you are done with it.  You need to out-dent those lines:

```
for i in indexes:
    if a_str[i-1] == ".":
        indexes.pop(i)

if len(indexes)>0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

You can replace those `if`-`else` lines with `return len(indexes) > 0`

Comment: I did that and it's returning the same problem.

Comment: Oh ok, I didnt know that abut remove(). That clears things up, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One line solution if you want to use list compression, you could also do it with a filter:

```
def xyz_there(a_str):
    return a_str[:3] == 'xyz' or any([not a_str[i-1] == '.' and a_str[i:i+3] == 'xyz' for i in range(1,len(a_str)-2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def xyz_there(a_str):
   all_indexes = re.finditer("xyz", a_str)
   with_dot_preceding = [[n.start(), n.end()] for n in all_indexes if a_str[n.start() - 1] == "."]
return with_dot_preceding

test = xyz_there(".xyz.xyz")
if(len(test) > 0):
    print True 
    print "True in %d places" % len(test)
```